# Hover over parent changes children elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have a hamburger menu. I want it so that when you hover over the hamburger menu, it changes the color of the span elements inside of it.

I want it so that when you hover over the hamburger menu, it changes the
 color of the span elements inside the hamburger menu. I tried to do

```
  .hamburger-menu:hover span {
      background-color: red;
  }
```

Here's the CSS for the hamburger-menu:

```
    .hamburger-menu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        outline: none;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 60.5px;
        height: 100%;
        background: none;
        border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;

        span {
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 5px;
            height: 2px;
            width: 20px;
            background-color: #a3a3a3;
            display: block;
            content: '';
            margin: 4px auto 0 auto;

            &:nth-child(1) {
                margin-top: 26px;
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
    <div class="hamburger-menu">
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Why are you keeping the css in a nested way?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy it's SCSS

Comment: @JacobGray Oh I see, I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Edited the scss file and use `&`

```
.hamburger-menu {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 10;
        outline: none;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 60.5px;
        height: 100%;
        background: none;
        border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
       /* add this */
        &:hover span {
           background-color:red;
        }

        span {
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 5px;
            height: 2px;
            width: 20px;
            background-color: #a3a3a3;
            display: block;
            content: '';
            margin: 4px auto 0 auto;

            &:nth-child(1) {
                margin-top: 26px;
            }
        }
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LLhefe2p/

Answer (score 1):

you must use pseudo class :hover

```
.hamburger-menu:hover span { 
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: I have copied your code and just implemented the pseudo class and it's working. when you want to change the style in CSS in the form of event handling such as hover you have to use pseudo class. Unless you want to use scripting

Answer (score 0):

you could use jQuery hover to either set a class, or change the css.

https://api.jquery.com/hover/

I would set a class on hover, rather than setting the colour with jquery.

```html
$('.burger-menu').hover(function(){

    $( this ).addClass('red' );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass('red' );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS can do this for you simply.  Just use something like this:

```
#container:hover .inner {
  opacity: 0.8 
}
```